# OptaPlanner:Java Error in runexamples.bat

Tags: optaplanner

Windows 10 
Installed latest java version (jdk1.8.0_111)
Downloaded optaplanner and tried to run runexamples.bat from command prompt

Error message: \Java\jdk1.8.0_111)... was unexpected at this time

Can you please help resolve?

Thanks

Comment: Can you copy paste the entire console log?

Comment: C:\Users\venkateswaranws\Documents\optaplanner-distribution-6.5.0.Final\optaplanner-distribution-6.5.0.Final\examples>runExamples.bat
Usage: runExamples.bat
Notes:
- Java must be installed. Get the JRE (http://www.java.com) or the JDK.
- For optimal performance, Java is recommended to be OpenJDK 7 or higher.
- For JDK, the environment variable JAVA_HOME should be set to the JDK installation directory
  For example: set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0"
- The working dir should be the directory of this script.

\Java\jdk1.8.0_111)... was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Problem solved.

1. we used c:\progra~2 instead of c:\program files (x86)

and

2. we used the environment variable _JAVA_OPTIONS

The program fired up once these were done. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. 1. we used c:\progra~2 instead of c:\program files (x86) and 2. we used the environment variable _JAVA_OPTIONS The program fired up once these were done. Thanks for your time

Comment: Anything we can change in the default [runExamples.bat](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-distribution/src/main/assembly/scripts/runExamples.bat) script so it would just work out of the box on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can install windows x64 instead of windows x86 versions. We had the same error message \Java\jdk1.8.0_111)... was unexpected at this time. After installing 64bit java and setting JAVA_HOME for jdk1.8.0_111, everything goes fine.